# single % syntax and #comment in <%= %>are not working in .erb files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, erb

I just took a look at http://ruby-doc.org/ruby-1.9/classes/ERB.html as well as http://ruby-doc.org/ruby-1.8/classes/ERB.html. I saw that the following is supported both in 1.8 and 1.9.

```
% a line of Ruby code
```

But after a tried it in a line of

```
% end ### changed from <% end %>
```

the browser simply shows % end in plain... Wondering what's the problem here?

**(updated) another question**, it seem when comment like #blabla appears in <%**=** %>, rails will get an error, any idea?

my code for another question:

```
<%= @page_title || 'Pragmatic Bookshelf' #magic @page_title; a if a is true, else b%>
```

Thanks

Comment: can you post your view code and error?

Comment: @krunal-shah I suspect <%= code %> does not allow #comment. dont't know if my guess is right or not...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a comment in ERB:

```
<%# Where is pancakes house? %>
```

whereas this is an error:

```
<%= # I'll cook you some eggs, Margie. %>
```

You cannot combine a comment and the `<%= %>` syntax.

In the documentation you linked to, you might notice the *optional -- see ERB.new* note in here:

```
% a line of Ruby code -- treated as <% line %> (optional -- see ERB.new)
```

And then, [`ERB.new`](http://ruby-doc.org/ruby-1.9/classes/ERB.html#M001617) has this to say:

> If *trim_mode* is passed a String containing one or more of the following modifiers, ERB will adjust its code generation as listed:
>
> `%  enables Ruby code processing for lines beginning with %`

So you probably don't have a *trim_mode* in your `ERB.new` options.

Comment: thanks. but for the 1st question, i tried to omit whitespace but still not working.

Comment: does <%= %> allow #comment inserted in?

Comment: @mu is too short could you explain why "You cannot combine a comment and the <%= %> syntax." ?

Comment: @draw: No, I can't explain it as I can't find a formal grammar or specification for ERB :) The best I can do is say that you're not allowed to because the ERB parser says "no". There are advantages and disadvantages to working in informal systems.

Answer (score 1):

If *trim_mode* is passed a String containing one or more of the following modifiers, ERB will adjust its code generation as listed:

% enables Ruby code processing for lines beginning with %